# subdomain htaccess index

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I have this structure

```
/
/-log
/-shop
/-wwwroot
/--shop
/--shop/-index.html
/--wp-content
/-- and so on
```

I want to redirect every visitors who surfs in to shop.mysite.com to the /--shop/-index.html file (shop.mysite.com/index.html). As it is now, they will come to the "normal" page mysite.com.

I have the right wildcard set.

My .htaccess looks like this (plain Wordpress).

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this right after `RewriteBase /`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^shop.mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /shop/index.html [L]
```

This only makes http://shop.mysite.com/ serve the file at shop/index.html, if you want to redirect all requests to the shop.mysite.com host, you'll need to craft a regular expression and point it to files in /shop.

---

> Is it regular expression which should be used here? How should that look?

You can add this below the above rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^shop.mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/shop/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /shop/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for answer Jon Lin! Almost there, now it works as I have described it. But I forgot to mention how the .htaccess should look like if I example have another file in the same cat (/shop/) which I also want to be able to surf to? Ex http://shop.mysite.com/check.html (or anything else not yet known). Is it regular expression which should be used here? How should that look?